# Java: fillings two vectors and sorting them

Tags: java, vector, comparator

How can I fill up two vectors and combine them with each other (either index or an object type in class). I guess if I use index to combine them, then the sorting can be handled with Collections.sort otherwise I have to create a comparator.

We have to code down to the Java 1.4 convention.

To make your imagination easier; it's a grid which has a sorting vector (rows) and a content vector (with all cols). They need to be filled in a vector and sorted.

Context: I have a GridBagLayout containing all components in a wierd order. I need to cycle through all components and fill them in the right grid order (gridx, gridy). For that solution I thought about two vectors, one defines the row and points to the vector containing it's cols. Either the sort will be be resolved while filling the vector or I have to sort it in a second step. I guess for java 4 there is no other approach than two vectors containing an object, right?

Comment: Sorry dude but your question is not very clear to me, probably you would like to rephrase it.

Comment: Maybe you're right... *sigh*

You have a GridBagLayout containing all components in a wierd order.
I need to cycle through all components and fill them in the right grid order (gridx, gridy). For that solution I thought about two vectors, one defines the row and points to the vector containing it's cols.

Either the sort will be be resolved while filling the vector or I have to sort it in a second step.

I guess for java 4 there is no other approach than two vectors containing an object, right?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify it; not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: Unrelated note: if you can (ie. barring legacy usage elsewhere in the code), you should drop the usage of deprecated Vector in favor of faster ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

The OO solution is to wrap the objects in both vectors in something that implements the comparing and keeps a pointer to the real object. This way, you can sort both vectors independent of each other and use the wrapper to get at the real object.

This is the "Decorator" design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I understand.  As input, you're given two vectors.  The first is an ordered list of row numbers that reference indices in the second vector.  The second vector is a list of somethings.  You would like a vector that contains the same objects as the second vector, but sorted in the order described in the first vector.

Assuming that's what you're trying to do, this is how I'd do it:

```
public class ThisHadBetterNotBeAHomeworkAssignmentYoungMan {

    public Vector orderContent(Vector indices, Vector content) {
       Object[] orderedStuff = new Object[content.size()];
       for( int i=0; i < indices.size(); i++ ) {
          orderedStuff[i] = content.get(((Integer)indices[i]).intVal());
       }
       return new Vector(orderedStuff);
    }
}
```

//Note that this is pretty rough code, and I have neither executed it nor bothered checking to see if you can pass an array of stuff into a Vector as a constructor, but you get the idea.

//note also that I'm not sure exactly what you're asking and could be entirely wrong.

Comment: your description on top is almost what I need. Except that the orderVector doesn't need to be same as contentVector. orderVector should have, in my opinion, just two index.